# Storing user inputs (Q & A ) in an array and retrieve the answer

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm a beginner in JavaScript & in this task I have I have to do the following;

- allow the user to enter questions and answer pairs in an html page which will be stored in an array.
- retrieve the answer when one of the questions from the array is asked (different boxes, labels)
- Reset the boxes when I press a button

So far, I just know how to store the user input in one single array, append it when a button is pressed and display it.

How do I have two different objects (Question & answer) in the same array that will be an input by the user in pairs and retrieve only the answer when the Question is input again? *It kind of works like a Manual Bot.*

```js
var myArr = [];

function pushData() {
  // get value from the input text
  var inputText = document.getElementById('inputText').value;

  // append data to the array
  myArr.push(inputText);

  var pval = "";

  for (i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    pval = pval + myArr[i] + "<br/>";
  }

  // display array data
  document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = pval;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title</title>
    <meta charset="windows-1252">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <input type="text" name="text" id="inputText" />
  <button onclick="pushData();">Show</button>
  <p id="pText"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: push an object like `{q: "the question text", a: "the answer value"}`

Comment: Wouldn't that require a separate text box? That doesn't give me my desired result unfortunately :(

Comment: sorry, skim-read the question, suggestion was for `How do I have two different objects (Question & answer) in the same array`

Comment: I think I might have phrased it wrong. I'm basically trying to create something similar to the interface. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an object? That way, you can store the Question/Answer pairs with the Question as the key and the answer as its value. Try this out:

```js
var myObj = {};

function pushData() {
  // get value from the input text
  var question = document.getElementById('inputQuestion').value;
  var answer = document.getElementById('inputAnswer').value;

  // add data to the object
  myObj[question] = answer;
}

function getAnswer() {
  var question = document.getElementById('inputRetrieveQuestion').value;

  if (myObj[question]) {
    document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = myObj[question];
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h3> Enter a Question/Answer </h3>
  Question <input type="text" name="question" id="inputQuestion" /> Answer <input type="text" name="answer" id="inputAnswer" />
  <button onclick="pushData()">Submit</button>
  </br>

  <h3> Retrieve an Answer </h3>
  Question <input type="text" name="question" id="inputRetrieveQuestion" />
  <button onclick="getAnswer()">Submit</button>
  </br>

  Answer:
  <div id="pText"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Even if I did use an object, any idea how I'd do the same thing using an array?